# Joining twice the same stream

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I would like use the joining collector twice on a same stream for produce a string like this `Tea:5 - Coffee:3 - Money:10` .

Drink is enum with an Bigdecimal attribute (price).

currently I done like this :

```
Map<Drink, Long> groupByDrink = listOfDrinks.stream().collect(groupingBy(identity(),counting()));

        String acc = groupByDrink.entrySet().stream().map(ite -> join(":", ite.getKey().code(), ite.getValue().toString())).collect(joining(" - "));

        acc += " - Money:" + groupByDrink.entrySet().stream().map(ite -> ite.getKey().price().multiply(valueOf(ite.getValue()))).reduce(ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think, you are overusing new features.

```
join(":", ite.getKey().code(), ite.getValue().toString())
```

bears no advantage over the classical

```
ite.getKey().code()+":"+ite.getValue()
```

Besides that, I’m not sure what you mean with “*use the joining collector twice on a same stream*”. If you want to use the joining collector for the summary element as well, you have to concat it as stream before collecting:

```
String acc = Stream.concat(
        groupByDrink.entrySet().stream()
            .map(ite -> ite.getKey().code()+":"+ite.getValue()),
        Stream.of("Money:" + groupByDrink.entrySet().stream()
            .map(ite -> ite.getKey().price().multiply(valueOf(ite.getValue())))
            .reduce(ZERO, BigDecimal::add).toString())
    ).collect(joining(" - "));
```

Comment: This code does not do both operations in the same pipeline. It creates **two** streams (`groupByDrink.entrySet().stream()`) and combines the results.

Comment: @Alexey: I never claimed that and there’s nothing in the question suggesting that this is wished. All this solution does, is using a single `joining` collector for all results, which seems to be, what the question is about. At least, it talks about the `joining` collector…

Comment: Maybe I did not undestand what OP wants to do. I thought s/he is unhappy that a stream is cteated twice from the `groupByDrink` map, and s/he wants to do it in one go.